# Regex: How to grab strings within quotes, commas, spaces, and new line?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of strings in a `.txt` file, and I want to grab the data within quotes, commas, spaces, and new line.

Here is the example of the listings:

> CurCode           "608", "840", "784", "036", "048", "124", "756", "156", "208", "978", "826", "344", "360", "376", "356", "392", "410", "414", "484", "458", "578", "554", "634", "643", "682", "752", "702", "764", "901", "840", "704", "710"

I have tried the different approaches from comments on similar questions but they don't seem to work for me.

Comment: you dont need regex to do that. Just use string.split

Comment: I have seen that you are facing issue to work around it, have you tried mine?

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: But these strings are in a .txt file. How will I be able to grab them?

Comment: @kenken `File.ReadAllText(fname)`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply split, trim and remove the quotes:

```
var list =
    str.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Trim().Replace("\"", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

for this partícular format, regex will fill your needs:

```
//sample created with http://regexhero.net/tester/
string strRegex = @"""(?:\d+)""";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"""608"", ""840"", ""784"", ""036"", ""048"", ""124"", ""756"", ""156"", ""208"", ""978"", ""826"", ""344"", ""360"", ""376"", ""356"", ""392"", ""410"", ""414"", ""484"", ""458"", ""578"", ""554"", ""634"", ""643"", ""682"", ""752"", ""702"", ""764"", ""901"", ""840"", ""704"", ""710""";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
   //Do your stuff with the value here: myMatch.Groups[0].Value 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `(:?` portion of your regex is just a typo, but why are you trying to use a non-capturing group anyway?  As it is, it matches a quote (`"`), an optional colon (`:`), one or more digits (`\d+`), and another quote (`"`).  The digits are captured in `Groups[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

Using string manipulation: (Recommended)

**Sample Code:**

```
var lst = sampleStr.Replace(""",""",",").Replace("CurCode ""","").TrimEnd('"').Split(',');
```

Using regex try out this pattern:

```
(?<=[,\s]\")(.*?)(?=\")
```

This pattern is enough capable to handle the quoted numbers and well as some string

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RSkySvSwod)

**Sample Code:**

```
MatchCollection mcol = regex.Matches(sampleStr,@"(?<=[,\s]\")(.*?)(?=\")");

foreach(Match m in mcoll)
{
    Debug.Print(m.ToString());  // See output window
}
```